# Using Infinite Scroll module with Views paging: Detrimental to Google SEO?

Tags: views, ajax, paging

I love using the Infinite Scroll module with Views. But does Google limit indexing to to only those first bunch of nodes which appear in the view?

I'm guessing that when using a regular pager, Google will dig deeper and index all subsequent pages in the view. But what does it do when ajax is used to move forward to the next batch of nodes as is the case with Infinite Scroll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it's not detrimental (well, not in the way you're thinking at least) - the standard pager links are hidden with infinite scroll, but still in the markup, so there's no problem from that perspective. Google will find and visit the subsequent pages as with a normal views pager.

The only question is whether Google apply some sort of penalty to the pages linked to *from* those hidden links. But that's something you'd need to get out of Google :)

Comment: The trick I've seen was to keep the links not simply hidden, but just below user's viewport. Other one was a link "view more", that's a link to next page and happens to turn on infinite scrolling if js is enabled. I guess both methods was implemented to make site work better with search engines.